# Compilation of large class hierarchy consumes lots of memory after adding boost::serialization

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, templates, serialization, boost

We needed serialization of quite large C++ class hierarchy with lots of inheritance, contraction, shared pointers, etc. I decided to use `boost::serialization` library.

My problem is that while compilation of this library on VS 2008 `cl` takes over 1 GB of RAM memory. I suppose this is caused by template-based serialization in Boost. This causes many problems with building whole project on weaker PCs. What's interesting, compilation time is not so much longer:

```
no serialization: 15:38 [mm:ss]
serialization:    17:06 [mm:ss]
```

My question is: is it possible to cut the memory usage? Maybe with longer compilation time?

#### Edit

This increase of used memory happens in several files during compilation of C++/CLI project which *actually uses* serialization from the library above. Without serialization `cl.exe` has peak memory on the largest file about 150 MB, usually not more than 80. Increase of memory use is about 4 to 8 times on several files.

Comment: You should include how much memory your cl takes without the serialization lib.

Comment: Since one cl.exe is launched for *each* cpp file during the build, you should check which cpp file uses the most memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem when using boost::serialization. Probably the only workaround is to split up the huge class in more encapsulated pieces. For some classes in my code, I also wrote a layer between my application classes and the serializer. This layer simplified the structur of the data to be saved. It even separated a larger "data" part and saved it using libz (the zip library) instead of using serialization everywhere.